# Changing from Flowplayer to Jwplayer - Could not connect to server

Tags: stream, live, jwplayer, rtmp

I'm trying to change over from flowplayer (current code below)

flowplayer("player", "http://churchwebsite.com/flowplayer-3.1.5.swf", {

```
    clip: { 
        url: 'livestream',
        live: 'true', 
        provider: 'influxis' 
    },  
    // streaming plugins are configured under the plugins node 
    plugins: {  
        influxis: { 
            url: 'http://churchwebsite.com/flowplayer.rtmp-3.1.3.swf', 

            netConnectionUrl:
                'rtmp://stream.s22.cpanelservices.com/somethinglive'
```

This is what I'm switching to

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
file: "rtmp://stream.s22.cpanelservices.com/somethinglive",
autostart: true,
controls: true,
height: 600,
width: 800,
```

Here's the information I have, not sure what to put in where.

rtmp://stream.s22.cpanelservices.com/somethinglive

rtmp://churchwebsite.com/live

I'm using Adobe flash media encoder to stream, and through there it shows

FMS URL:  rtmp://stream.s22.cpanelservices.com/somethinglive

Stream: livestream

Comment: Please give us a link to your page.

Comment: This is a password protected website, as the pastor does not want the service going out to anyone other than the members. Could you please email me
vssr0027@gmail.com
I will post the results on here, minus the direct page information

Comment: If you can post a link, we can debug easier.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of RTMP streaming:

In the `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"</script>
```

In the `<body>` section:

```
<div id="#myElement">Loading the player...</div>
<script>
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "rtmp://example.com/application/mp4:myVideo.mp4",
    image: "/assets/myVideo.jpg",
    height: 360,
    width: 640
});
</script>
```

This assumes that the three JW Player script files (**jwplayer.js. jwplayer.html5.js, and jwplayer.flash.swf**) are in the same directory as your index.html. Otherwise, your **src** attribute needs to point to where you've actually stashed them. All three files need to be together, in any event.

The **file** attribute for the stream depends upon what, exactly, you're providing. See the JW Player configuration guide: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430358-using-rtmp-streaming

Comment: But where am I getting the mp4:myvideo.mp4 out of rtmp://stream.s22.cpanelservices.com/somethinglive
Or
rtmp://churchwebsite.com/live

Comment: You're providing the stream, aren't you? Don't you know what the URL is? I certainly can't guess.

Comment: I do not. I took this over and have zero experience. Any information I have, I've written here.  Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it.